# Programmatically get html of top.links in magento

Tags: html, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to get the html of `top.links` using the following ways:

- `$blockHtml = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getBlockHtml('top.links')`
- `$blockHtml = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('top.links').toHtml()`
- `$blockHtml = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getBlock('top.links')->toHtml()`

None of above is working for me, how I can do this?

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

I used

```
$layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
$block = $layout->createBlock('page/html')->setTemplate('page/html/top.links.phtml')->toHtml();
```

With the help of this question [Add Top Links on condition basis in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706544/add-top-links-on-condition-basis-in-magento?rq=1) but still no luck. During this try I found that the use of `top.links.phtml` is deprecated, any idea which template should I use for the links?

I think there is some dependency for `top.links.phtml` file, that's why it isn't working, when I tried to get `footer.phtml` it worked perfectly with above method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow! I was able to find a correct answer finally :) [Load block outside Magento, and apply current template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347384/load-block-outside-magento-and-apply-current-template)

So by following the the above question's answer, I did this to get generated top.links

```
    $layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
    $layout->getUpdate()
            ->addHandle('default')
            ->load();

    $layout->generateXml()
            ->generateBlocks();

    echo $layout->getBlock('top.links')->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like the op, I tried many ways without success. The following simple line finally does it:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('top.links')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have created CMS block named 'block_identifier' from admin panel. Then following will be code to call them in .phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please,used the belowCodes.This will be working

```
   echo  $this->getLayout()->getcreateBlock('page/template_links')->toHtml();
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, but it didn't work for me, it returned empty string. Actually I am writing an API to get the content of `top.links.phtml` so don't know what else is required for that template to be rendered..